# grunt skip script on deployment

Tags: less, gruntjs, yeoman

I use less.js to code my css. When I build the project (grunt-server, grunt), the grunt-contrib-less plugin converts the less.js style to my main.css file. I only include this file in my index.html.

This works great for deploying, but for developing not so much. I need to build the project or run "grunt less" to view changes of my css.

I'm guessing there is an easier way of doing this, but i'm new with the grunt en yeoman stuff so I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch), together with grunt-contrib-less.